# Autoload no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, front-end, autoload

Estou iniciando em Front End e queria saber qual a melhor técnica e ferramenta/biblioteca para efetuar o carregamento dos arquivos de dependência no **JavaScript**.

Sinto que poderia adicionar no meu html apenas um arquivo .js e neste arquivo controlar o carregamento das dependências neste. Devo utilizar alguma biblioteca  para isto ou o JavaScript faz isso nativamente?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) ou o [bower](https://bower.io) para gerenciar as dependências do seu projeto.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Essas opções são ótimas para o gerenciamento de dependências mesmo mas, estou procurando uma forma simplificada de carregar os arquivos automaticamente sem precisar ficar incluindo manualmente no html com a tag `<script>`.